# Create nested list from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a simple pandas dataframe with two columns. i would like to generate a nested list of those two columns.

```
geo = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [40.672304, 40.777169, 40.712196], 
                'lon': [-73.935385, -73.988911, -73.957649]})
```

my solution to this problem is the following:

```
X = [[i] for i in geo['lat'].tolist()]
Y = [i for i in geo['lon'].tolist()]

for key, value in enumerate(X):
    X[key].append(Y[key])
```

however, i feel there must be a better way than this.

thanks!

Comment: Are you after `geo.values.tolist()`?

Comment: @MaxU pundit worthy

Comment: @piRSquared I agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pandas` is built on top of `numpy`. A `DataFrame` stores its `values` in a `numpy` array, which has a `tolist` method.

```
>>> geo = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [40.672304, 40.777169, 40.712196],
    ...:                 'lon': [-73.935385, -73.988911, -73.957649]})
    ...:
>>> geo.values
>>>
array([[ 40.672304, -73.935385],
       [ 40.777169, -73.988911],
       [ 40.712196, -73.957649]])
>>>
>>> geo.values.tolist()
[[40.672304, -73.935385], [40.777169, -73.988911], [40.712196, -73.957649]]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
out_list = []
for index, row in geo.iterrows():
    out_list.append([row.lat, row.long])
```

Comment: thanks! that is more concise! @MaxU's was even more concise though.

Comment: **Note**: `.iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish, use it only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Agreed - I've learnt a lot more about pandas in the years since and the accepted answer is far, far better.